# characterization of multivariate normal distribution by its one-dimensional marginals

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random vector in $\mathbb R^n$. we say $X$ has the normal distribution $N(\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{V})$ if it has the density function:

$$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{D/2}|\boldsymbol{V}|^{1/2}} \exp \left( -\frac{1}{2}(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^T \boldsymbol{V}^{-1}(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu}) \right) $$

Using this definition, I wonder how to show that $X$ has a multivariate normal distribution if and only if every one dimensional marginal $\langle X,\theta \rangle$ is normal (in one-dimensional sense).

I have trouble in both directions:

(1) For the forward direction, I am not sure how to find the density of $\langle X,\theta \rangle$ for a fix vector $\theta$ so that I can show the one-dimensional marginals are normal.

(2) For the backword direction, a hint says we may use the Cramer-Wold device, which says the sequence $X_n$ converges to $X_0$ in distribution if $\langle X_n,\theta \rangle$ converges to $\langle X_0,\theta \rangle$ in distribution for all fix vector $\theta$. But I am not sure how to use this theorem in the proof (where is the convergence?).

This is the Exercise 3.3.4 in Vershynin's high dimensional probability book. But I can't find it in some other prbability books, say Durrett.

Comment: I've only read part of that book but happen to really like it and chapter 3 in particular.  If you want to prove this more easily, ignore the suggestions and work in a transform space (i.e. MGF or CF).  If you work with say, the Moment Generating Function, the problem reduces to linear algebra.  It's a more fitting solution for a book that doesn't use measure theory and is heavy on linear algebra.

Comment: Does the hint say to use the C-W "device" or just to use the C-W theorem?

Comment: @kimchilover Whatever, do you think you can prove it with the C-W "device" in your mind to prove this，as well as showing how it is implied from the C-W theorem above (or able to be proved independently)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Vershynin's book, so don't know what ingredients may be legitimately used in answering his homework exercise.  So I will try to use as little as I can to give a proof that normality of all linear forms in a random vector implies the vector itself is normally distributed.

Zeroth, you need to know the characteristic function of gaussian random variables and gaussian random vectors.

First, the [Cramér–Wold theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Wold_theorem) tells us that the distribution of $X$ is specified by the distributions of all the linear forms in $X$.  If you believe that the characteristic function $\phi(a)=E[\exp(i\langle a,X\rangle)]$ of $X$ determines the distribution of $X$, this is easy to see, as the characteristic function $\phi_a$ of the scalar random variable $\langle a,X\rangle$ is simply $t\mapsto \phi(ta)$, that is, $\phi$ restricted to the line through $a$. To know all the functions $\phi_a$ is to know $\phi$.

Second. since the $i$-th component of $X$ is a linear form in $X$, and hence gaussian, and hence with finite variance, we know each of $E[X^2_i]<\infty$, and hence (by Cauchy-Schwarz) the covariance matrix $\mathbf V$ is finite.  As is the mean vector, $\mathbf \mu$.  Now we know the expectation and variance of the linear form $\langle a,X\rangle$, namely $\langle a,\mathbf \mu\rangle $ and $a'\mathbf V a$.  And hence the characteristic function of the gaussian rv. $\langle a,X\rangle$, with that mean and variance, namely, $\phi_a(t) =\exp( it\langle a,\mathbf \mu\rangle - t^2 a'\mathbf V a/2)$.

Finally, put these together: the characteristic function of a $N(\mathbf \mu,\mathbf V)$ random vector (call it $\varphi)$ has exactly the same restrictions to lines through $a$:
for all $a$, we have $\varphi_a(t)=\phi_a(t)$, for all $a$ and all $t$.  So $\phi=\varphi$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks! But I think the version of C-W in the wikipedia says is about the convergence (a random vector converges to a random vector X iff the marginals converge to marginals of X). Does that *imply* the one you are using, namely two random vectors are identical in distribution iff  their marginals are identical in distribution?

Comment: The first sentence of that article says: "In mathematics, the Cramér–Wold theorem in measure theory states that a Borel probability measure on $ \mathbb {R} ^{k}$ is uniquely determined by the totality of its one-dimensional projections." which is exactly what I used.  The convergence stuff (the C-W "device") is an obvious consequence, but my argument does not use it.